# Django queryset - transfrom json object

Tags: python, json, serialization, django-queryset

I have a problem with django queryset:

I have in my html file form like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="user[username]"/>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="user[password]"/>
<input type="number" placeholder="Mobile number" name="mobile_number"/>
<button type="submit" id="register-form-create">create</button>
```

then I serialize it with `.serializeJSON()`,

In django when I use `json.loads`, I am getting output like:

```
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'zg7Sl25DiXwZPnwd9QyhdffdfXfQnOh', 'user[username]': 'user1', 'user[password]': 'password1234', 'mobile_number': '45214578563'}
```

What do I have to do to get:

```
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'zg7Sl25DiXwZPnwd9QyhdffdfXfQnOh',
'user':{
        'username': 'user1',
        'password': 'password1234'
        },
'mobile_number': 45214578563
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making serializer in seialzier:

```
`user_serializer=UserSerializer(data=create_user_request.data)
 mobile_number_serializer=MobileNumberSerializer(data=create_user_request.data)
user_serializer.is_valid()
mobile_number_serializer.is_valid()
final_dict = {"user": user_serializer.data}
final_dict.update(mobile_number_serializer.data)`
```

It gave me data with i wanted, if somebody can do it with more elegant way please share.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try it when sending data to HTML file in django:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(info))
```